# Convert Class Object to String

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I have an assignment for a class that requires me to convert a class object, `clock_time`, to a string using two required, instructor-defined empty functions: `to_string()`  and an overloaded << operator. I am not able to get it to work and I am unsure why.

```
clock_time::clock_time(int h, int m, int s)
{
    set_time(h, m, s);
}

void clock_time::set_time(int h, int m, int s)
{
    _seconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;
}

string to_string(clock_time c)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << c;
    return ss.str();
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, clock_time c)
{
    out << to_string(c);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: The `to_string` method uses the `operator<<` overload for `clock_time`. The `operator<<` uses the `to_string` method. Kind of have a chicken and egg thing going on here, my friend.

Comment: I got the operator overload to work, but I still cannot get the `to_string` function to work. Any suggestions to start?

Comment: @WallaceMogerty What's the definition of `clock_time`?

Comment: @AmiTavory `clock_time` returns the time in seconds given int values for hour, minutes, and seconds. I have implemented methods within the class to get the hour, minute, etc.

Comment: Better add `clock_time` to the question. Hard to do much more than guess without it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The crux of the problem is the `to_string` method uses the `operator<<` overload for `clock_time`. Unfortunately, The `operator<<` overload uses the `to_string` method. Obviously this can't work because it's going to go around in circles forever.

So how do we fix it up so that it can work?

We uncouple `to_string` and `operator<<` so that they don't call each other.

First off, let's define a bogus example `clock_time` because it's missing and we can't do jack all without it.

```
class clock_time
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, clock_time c);
}
```

Note the declaration of `operator<<` as a `friend` function of `clock_time`s. This allows `operator<<` to break encapsulation and use the private members of `clock_time`. This might not be necessary depending on how `clock_time` has been defined, but for this example, it's pretty much the key to the whole shebang.

Next we implement `operator<<`

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, clock_time c)
{
    out << c.hour << ":" << c.minute << ":" << c.second;
    return out;
}
```

I've chosen this output format because it's what I expect to see on a digital clock. The Law of Least Surprise says give people what they expect and you'll have fewer bugs and bad feelings. Confuse people and... Well remember what happened with when Microsoft pulled the start menu from Windows 8? Or when Coke changed their formula?

I'm doing `operator<<` first because of personal preference. I'd rather do the grunt work here because it's easier on my brain than doing it in `to_string` for some reason.

Now we're ready to implement the `to_string` function.

```
string to_string(clock_time c)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << c;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Surprise! It's exactly the same as OP originally implemented it. Because `to_string` and `operator<<` have been uncoupled, `operator<<` is available for use in `to_string`. You could do it the other way around, so long as one of the functions does the heavy lifting for the other. Both could also do all of the work, but why? Twice as many places to screw things up.